# Disable the span from any action

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem in my project.
I created something like keyboard for hangman game with span.
In click situation I need to have disabled span for that letter and if user choose wrong letter the hangman image should be change.
But when I click any button it looks like it is disabled because I changed the color

```
. clickedLetter{

    background-color :....

    opacity:.1;

    pointer-events: none;

}
```

But the letter is still clickable and when you click on disabled letter(span) the image of hangman going to change .

I want to add something to stop any action

It is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

if(e.target.className ==='boxForLetter')

{ e.target.classList.add("clickedLetter");}

let clickedLetter= e.target.innerHTML;
```

.......

....

...

.

I appreciate any thoughts about this problem

Comment: Can you share your code snippet so we can see how `boxForLetter` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your if statement.

You need to run the code in your if statement NOT below it. If you run your hangman code BELOW your if statement in a delegated click handler, any click will trigger the hangman code. Also, I would recommend checking if the classlist contains a class, not if the class name equals something. This is more modern and allows for more classes on the objects.

```
if(e.target.classList.contains('boxForLetter'))    
{
   //run hangman code here
   e.target.classList.add("clickedLetter");
   let clickedLetter= e.target.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I put the code outside the if statement by mistake. Now is working correctly. I appreciate your help 

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem right, you want to remove the click event if it is already clicked. It may be actually done using `pointer-events: none` which disables the event trigger.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  if (e.target.className === 'boxForLetter') {
    e.target.classList.add("clickedLetter");
  }

  let clickedLetter = e.target.innerHTML;

});
```

```css
.boxForLetter {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.boxForLetter.clickedLetter {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxForLetter">
</div>
<div class="boxForLetter">
</div>
<div class="boxForLetter">
</div>
<div class="boxForLetter">
</div>
<div class="boxForLetter">
</div>
<div class="boxForLetter">
</div>
```

Comment: I have used pointer-events: none in my . clickedLetter class